# MongoDB Querying Large Datasets

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Lets say I have simple document structure like:

```
    {
     "item": { 
          "name": "Skittles",
          "category": "Candies & Snacks"
     }
    }
```

On my search page, whenever user searches for product name, I want to have a filter options by category.

Since categories can be many (like 50 types) I cannot display all of the checkboxes on the sidebar beside the search results. I want to only show those which have products associated with it in the results. So if none of the products in search result have a category, then do not show that category option.

Now, the item search by name itself is paginated. I only show 30 items in a page. And we have tens of thousands of items in our database.

I can search and retrieve all items from all pages, then parse the categories. But if i retrieve tens of thousands of items in 1 page, it would be really slow.

Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: You can use aggregation and groupby category and project only category.

[{$group: {
  _id: "$item.category"

  }}]

Comment: would it be faster to project only category? can you pls explain how it works internally, i thought it still would read large no of objects in all pages?

Comment: It has to read all the documents to get the category right?
But only things is all this happens at the DB layer and it just returns the categories found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches based on your workflow and see what works the best in your situation. Some good candidate for the solution are

1. Use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/index.html) prior to running the query on large dataset
2. Use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) as @Lucia suggested

```
[{$group: { _id: "$item.category" }}]
```

3. Use another datastore(either redis or mongo itselff) to store intelligence on categories

Finally based on the approach you choose and the inflow of requests for filters, you may want to consider [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html) some fields

P.S. You're right about how aggregation works, unless you have a match filter as first stage, it will fetch all the documents and then applies the next stage.